# PHP form called to HTML file doesn't work when other forms are present

Tags: php, html, forms

I have multiple forms in a PHP file that I call with the 'include' command. If I put the include command before the other forms in the HTML page then it works. The problem is that I need to call the 'include' command below the other forms. The solution I came up with was to call the PHP file at the beginning of the page and hide the div. I then called the file again at the bottom of the page which fixed the problem. Is there another solution? Why is it doing this?

Non working example:

```
    <form></form>
    <form></form>
    include 'phpfilewithotherforms.php';
```

working example but not viable:

```
    include 'phpfilewithotherforms.php';
    <form></form>
    <form></form>
```

working example:

```
    <div style="display:none;">include 'phpfilewithotherforms,php';</div>
    <form></form>
    <form></form>
    include 'phpfilewithotherforms.php';
```

Sample of PHP file that I'm calling:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<div style='padding:20px;margin:15px;background:offwhite;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:lightgray;'>" .
    "<form method='post' name='example'>" .
    "<span class='detail'><b>Title:</b>  " .  
    $row['mytitle'] .
    "      " .
    "<input type='hidden' value='" . stripslashes($row['mytitle']) . "' . name='title'>" .
    "<span style='float:right'>" .
    "<input type='submit' value='Edit' name='edit'>" .
    "<input type='submit' value='Preview' name='preview'>" .
    "</span>" .
    "</form>" .
    }
```

Comment: Maybe use output buffering to prevent data from being sent to the browser before the completed html page is generated.

Comment: I had a similar problem that had me stumped, as Danny says, use ob_start and ob_flush to force a sequential order to the browser. That was my only workaround, never found out why it didn't work though, as I'd strictly sequenced the <form>s.

Comment: Thank you guys. Using a php buffer did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work in order. I would split the included file in two, one with the code needed before forms, and the other with the code needed after forms.

Comment: So is the way I'm doing it the best solution or am I just using a workaround?

Comment: Looked at your code. First of all, I would check your error_log for any syntaxis mistake. In PHP, there's no need no concatenate lines. In addition, take a look at your HTML, there are some extras ".".

Answer (score 0):

I usually write PHP inside HTML with `<? PHP CODE ?>`

```
<div style="display:none;"><?include 'phpfilewithotherforms,php';?></div>
```

Are you missing those?